# ruby on rails omniauth and omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

My app, made in ruby on rails, uses omniauth and omniauth-facebook gems. It consists of a 'Log In with Facebook' button. It works fine in localhost - people can log in with Facebook - but I can't get it working on my live server. As far as I can see I've changed the relevant details, but is there something I'm missing?

As I said, it works fine in localhost:3000. I've changed these details to try get it working at www.example.com, but I keep getting the error message:

```
Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

In my config/oauth.yml file I have:

```
development:
  facebook:
    app_id: "12345"
    app_secret: "abcde"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

staging: &staging
  facebook:
    app_id: "12345"
    app_secret: "abcde"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

test:
  <<: *staging

production:
  facebook:
    app_id: "12345678"
    app_secret: "abcdefgh"
```

I've changed the app_id and app_secret in 'production' to match my the id and secret of my application, which I made in Facebook.

In environments/production.rb I've put:

```
  # Need this here for mailing purposes
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.example.com' }
```

In environments/development.rb I've put:

```
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.example.com' }
```

Am I overlooking something? Maybe there's something I need to change in my Facebook Apps section, where it gave me the id and secret? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's your App Domains settings? is it `example.com`?

Comment: In Facebook where it says 'App Domains' I have www.example.com.

Comment: And in 'Website with Facebook Login, site url:' I have http://www.example.com/

Answer (score 0):

On Website with Facebook Login site url should be set to your website's URL And on App Domains set to your host, example :

App Domain:: `example.com`

Site Url: `http://example.com/`

And In `environments/production.rb` You should put:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
```

Comment: Cheers for that, thanks. Although still couldn't get it working. I put App Domain and Site Url exactly as described. Anything else it could be? I keep getting that message, 'Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration....' You can see it here, click on the Facebook button.http://populisto.com/login

Comment: @chamini2 Yes, I did, but can't remember how. In any case I've rebuilt my project in rails4 and ruby2. These tutorials are very helpful-https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me when I had all the settings done correctly. Turns out the App ID and App Secret had somehow changed along the way on my Facebook dashboard. You might have made a change on your dashboard that somehow changed the ID and Secret.Just confirm those details again